# CakePHP Search by the count of related table

Tags: cakephp, relationship

i need to make a search, filtering by the "COUNT" of a related table, but i cant do this..

Here is the query:

```
            $this->paginate = array
            (
             'Establishment' => array
             (
              'conditions' => array
              (
               'EstablishmentsCategory.slug' => $category,
              ),
              'limit'      => 10,
              'order'      => $order,
              'fields'     => array('Establishment.*'),
              'contain'    => array
              (
               'EstablishmentsCategory',
               'EstablishmentsImage',
               'EstablishmentsCoupon' => array('fields' => array('id'))
              )
             )
            );

        $data = $this->paginate('Establishment');
```

Now this return array like this:

```
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Establishment] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [establishments_category_id] => 1
                [slug] => xxxxxx
                [name] => xxxxxx
                [description] => xxxxxx
                [active] => 0
                [modified] => 2012-01-25 15:31:23
                [created] => 2011-07-29 10:03:51
            )

        [EstablishmentsCategory] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
            )

        [EstablishmentsCoupon] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [establishment_id] => 2
                    )

            )

        [EstablishmentsImage] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [establishment_id] => 2
                        [image] => fsdfsdf.jpg
                        [created] => 2012-01-10 11:34:06
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [establishment_id] => 2
                        [image] => werwerwer.jpg
                        [created] => 2012-01-10 11:34:06
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 4
                        [establishment_id] => 2
                        [image] => werwerwer.jpg
                        [created] => 2012-01-10 11:34:06
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 7
                        [establishment_id] => 2
                        [image] => werwerer2.jpg
                        [created] => 2012-01-10 13:31:01
                    )

            )

    )
```

The problem: I need to find, all "Establishments", thah have ONE OR MORE "EstablishmentsCoupon". I dont find the solution of this :S

Comment: What's wrong to your return? When you use 'contain' statement, you're making a query with inner join, so, returns only Establishments that have EstablishmentsCoupon.

Comment: Actually, the array return Establishment with EstablishmentsCoupon and without EstablishmentsCoupon, i need only the Establishment have one or more EstablishmentsCoupon.
In this case i have one EstablishmentsCoupon, but if the Establishment NOT HAVE ANY EstablishmentsCoupon (empty array), i need to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by using a `group` clause with a `having` statement.

***But, be warned, this may not work if your query requires a recursive setting that splits the query across multiple queries to get the EstablishmentCoupons etc.***

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'Establishment' => array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'EstablishmentsCategory.slug' => $category,
        ),
        'limit' => 10,
        'order' => $order,
        'fields' => array('Establishment.*, count(EstablishmentsCoupon.id) as ec_count'),
        'contain' => array(
            'EstablishmentsCategory',
            'EstablishmentsImage',
            'EstablishmentsCoupon' => array(
                'fields' => array('id')
            )
        ),
        'group' => array('Establishment.* HAVING ec_count > 0'),
    )
);

$data = $this->paginate('Establishment');
```

In the above code I've added an `ec_count` to the `fields` parameter, and then added a `group` parameter that uses a `having` clause based on that `ec_count`.

If you get a query syntax problem regarding the group, try using explicit fields from Establishment rather than using Establishment.* (which is a bad way of doing things as you're likely not using all the fields and don't know what you're getting anyway).

Again, this may not work depending on your query path, but this pattern has worked in one of the systems I've worked on.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a belongsTo association (and Coupon belongs to Establishment), you could enable [`counterCache`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html?highlight=countercache#countercache-cache-your-count) on your Coupon model.  When counterCache is enabled, Cake will track how many coupons each establishment has.

You could then search for Establishments with a simple find condition:

```
$this->Establishment->find( 'all', 
    conditions => array('Establishment.coupon_count >' => 0 )
    );
```